# inline-block span behaviors unexpectedly in HTML

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make some `span`s placed next to each other, and I expected them to act like below:
[image]

So, I coded like below, and it worked just as I expected:

```css
.block {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2vw;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
        <span class="block">content1
        </span>
        <span class="block">content2
        </span>
        <span class="block">content3
        </span>
</body>
</html>
```

But, if `span` has no text inside, it moves upward a bit:

```css
.block {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2vw;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
        <span class="block">
        </span>
        <span class="block">content2
        </span>
        <span class="block">content3
        </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if `span` has more than one line, it goes upward. As it have more lines, it goes upward further:

```css
.block {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2vw;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
        <span class="block">content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 content1 
        </span>
        <span class="block">content2
        </span>
        <span class="block">content3
        </span>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get them not to move regardless of the length of their contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the default [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for inline elements is baseline. Change it to middle or top to get what you want:

```css
.block {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 25vh;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="block">
        </span>
<span class="block">content2
        </span>
<span class="block">content3
        </span>
```